# Airlfow Execution Timeout not working well

Tags: airflow

I've set 'execution_timeout': timedelta(seconds=300) parameter on many tasks. When the execution timeout is set on task downloading data from Google Analytics it works properly - after ~300 seconds is the task set to failed. The task downloads some data from API (python), then it does some transformations (python) and loads data into PostgreSQL.
Then I've a task which executes only one PostgreSQL function - execution sometimes takes more than 300 seconds but I get this (task is marked as finished successfully).

```
*** Reading local file: /home/airflow/airflow/logs/bulk_replication_p2p_realtime/t1/2020-07-20T00:05:00+00:00/1.log
[2020-07-20 05:05:35,040] {__init__.py:1139} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: bulk_replication_p2p_realtime.t1 2020-07-20T00:05:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2020-07-20 05:05:35,051] {__init__.py:1139} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: bulk_replication_p2p_realtime.t1 2020-07-20T00:05:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2020-07-20 05:05:35,051] {__init__.py:1353} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-07-20 05:05:35,051] {__init__.py:1354} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2020-07-20 05:05:35,051] {__init__.py:1355} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-07-20 05:05:35,098] {__init__.py:1374} INFO - Executing <Task(PostgresOperator): t1> on 2020-07-20T00:05:00+00:00
[2020-07-20 05:05:35,099] {base_task_runner.py:119} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'run', 'bulk_replication_p2p_realtime', 't1', '2020-07-20T00:05:00+00:00', '--job_id', '958216', '--raw', '-sd', 'DAGS_FOLDER/bulk_replication_p2p_realtime.py', '--cfg_path', '/tmp/tmph11tn6fe']
[2020-07-20 05:05:37,348] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 958216: Subtask t1 [2020-07-20 05:05:37,347] {settings.py:182} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=10, pool_recycle=1800, pid=26244
[2020-07-20 05:05:39,503] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 958216: Subtask t1 [2020-07-20 05:05:39,501] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor LocalExecutor
[2020-07-20 05:05:39,857] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 958216: Subtask t1 [2020-07-20 05:05:39,856] {__init__.py:305} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/airflow/airflow/dags/bulk_replication_p2p_realtime.py
[2020-07-20 05:05:39,894] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 958216: Subtask t1 [2020-07-20 05:05:39,894] {cli.py:517} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: bulk_replication_p2p_realtime.t1 2020-07-20T00:05:00+00:00 [running]> on host dwh2-airflow-dev
[2020-07-20 05:05:39,938] {postgres_operator.py:62} INFO - Executing: CALL dw_system.bulk_replicate(p_graph_name=>'replication_p2p_realtime',p_group_size=>4 , p_group=>1, p_dag_id=>'bulk_replication_p2p_realtime', p_task_id=>'t1')
[2020-07-20 05:05:39,960] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2020-07-20 05:05:39,953] {base_hook.py:83} INFO - Using connection to: id: postgres_warehouse. Host: XXX Port: 5432, Schema: XXXX Login: XXX Password: XXXXXXXX, extra: {}
[2020-07-20 05:05:39,973] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2020-07-20 05:05:39,972] {dbapi_hook.py:171} INFO - CALL dw_system.bulk_replicate(p_graph_name=>'replication_p2p_realtime',p_group_size=>4 , p_group=>1, p_dag_id=>'bulk_replication_p2p_realtime', p_task_id=>'t1')
[2020-07-20 05:23:21,450] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2020-07-20 05:23:21,449] {timeout.py:42} ERROR - Process timed out, PID: 26244
[2020-07-20 05:23:36,453] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2020-07-20 05:23:36,452] {jobs.py:2562} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
```

Does anyone know how to enforce execution timeout out for such long running functions? It seems that the execution timeout is evaluated once the PG function finish.

Answer (score 1):

Airflow uses the [`signal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) module from the standard library to affect a timeout. [In Airflow it's used to hook into these system signals](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/utils/timeout.py#L45-L46) and request that the calling process be notified in `N` seconds and, should the process still be inside the context (*see the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods on the class*) it will raise an `AirflowTaskTimeout` exception.

Unfortunately for this situation, there are certain classes of system operations that cannot be interrupted. This is actually called out in the `signal` documentation:

> A long-running calculation implemented purely in C (such as regular expression matching on a large body of text) may run uninterrupted for an arbitrary amount of time, regardless of any signals received. **The Python signal handlers will be called when the calculation finishes.**

To which we say "But I'm not doing a long-running calculation in C!" -- yeah for Airflow this is almost *always* due to uninterruptable I/O operations.

The highlighted sentence above (*emphasis mine*) nicely explains why the handler is still triggered even after the task is allowed to (*frustratingly!*) finish, well beyond your requested timeout.